# Setting innerHTML to empty string "" does NOT trigger the desired layout shift. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, photoshop

In my Photoshop plugin, I have the following div element:

```
<div class="user_selection_text photoshop_document"></div>
```

This gets updated with text by user input at some point like so:

```
document.querySelector(".photoshop_document").innerHTML = formattedPath;
```

When it goes from an empty div, to having text inside of it? That text takes up space, causing a downward layout shift of the elements below it, as expected. However when I later try to reset it to an empty string? Like so?

```
document.querySelector(".photoshop_document").innerHTML = "";
```

It does NOT trigger the desired layout shift where it reverts back to the previous spacing of the elements. In other words, it continues to treat the layout of the elements as if there's text inside of there, even though it's been returned back to an empty div.

The only way I found to make this work is to hide the element, use an arbitrary setTimeout of 20 or so milliseconds, then display it again -- and only THEN will it display the elements with the desired spacing given that the divs are now empty:

```
document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.display = "none";  
document.querySelector(".photoshop_document").innerHTML = "";
setTimeout(() => {document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.display = "block"}, 20); // toggles visibility to patch aforementioned bug;
```

Is there any way to avoid having to use this awful workaround, and instead have it correctly update the div to have the spacing I want when I revert those divs back to containing empty strings?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m unable to reproduce the problem as stated. If you include a runnable snippet, and test it gives the same problem, it would help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth: It is most likely a bug specific to Photoshop. Photoshop development is notoriously buggy, compared against modern browsers. I thankfully found a functional workaround that I describe in my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use this moronic workaround where I clone and replace the element. This allows for the functionally instantaneous update I wanted:

```
document.querySelector(".photoshop_document").innerHTML = "";
const photoshop_document_div = document.querySelector(".photoshop_document");
const photoshop_document_div_clone = photoshop_document_div.cloneNode(false);
photoshop_document_div.parentNode.replaceChild(photoshop_document_div_clone, photoshop_document_div);
```